# Does the way my firebase database is structured affect scalability of firebase with geofire?

Tags: database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, geofire

I am creating an app with firebase. I am using geofire to allow each user to find nearby users of my app. I was wondering if the way my database is structured will affect the speed of the query when there are hundreds of thousands or even millions of users?

I couldn't find an answer to my question online and reading the documentation for geofire, didn't really clear this up for me either. Currently my database is structured like this:

```
users: {
   userID: {
       First Name: "Joe"
       Last Name: "Smith"
       location: {
           g: "9qrq9824l3"
           l: {
             0: 24.1439871
             1: 413.342499
```

Will structuring my database like this (by placing the geofire location info under each users userID) affect loading speed when there are many users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The performance of reading data from Firestore is purely based on the amount of data you read. The number of documents in the collection has no effect on query performance.

I don't see how the structure you proposed will affect the speed with which data can be read/queried.